# raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I want to create a record, and I partially succeeded. But here's the problem, I can't record 2, I get the following error. What am I doing wrong?

Error :

```
  File "C:\Users\bilgi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\bilgi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Example Code :

```
def loadUsers(self):
        # Dosya var?
        if os.path.exists('AccInformation.json'): # True ise......
            with open('AccInformation.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                users = json.load(file)
                
                for user in users:
                    user = json.load(user)
                    newUser = Account(user_id = user['user_id'], firstName = user['first_name'], lastName = user['last_name'], 
                                      email = user['email'], username = user['username'], 
                                      password = user['password'], accountKEY = user['AccountKEY'])
                    
                    self.users.append(newUser)
                print(self.users)
        else:
            print("""'AccInformation' adlı Dosya bulunamadı.""")
```

Comment: what's the content of `AccInformation.json`?

Comment: Are you sure that AccInformation.json contains valid JSON? Also, **user = json.load(user)** won't work because *user* will be a string rather than a file descriptor

Comment: AccInformation.json content this ;

["{\"user_id\": 518990642826, \"firstName\": \"Asdf\", \"lastName\": \"CCCC\", \"email\": \"eee@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"Einsatzgruppens\", \"password\": \"123456\", \"accountKEY\": \"31AI-TR9F-6GMP-S7DE-KJOC-V0Z4\"}"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So without knowing the contents of `AccInformation.json` it's difficult to properly answer this question, however I imagine it is a JSON with a list of dict items that represent separate users.

Based on that, the below code should work...

```py
import os
import json


def loadUsers(self):
    # Dosya var?
    if os.path.exists("AccInformation.json"):  # True ise......
        with open("AccInformation.json", encoding="utf-8") as infile:
            users = json.load(infile)
        # return indent here as we've already loaded the file

        for user in users:
            newUser = Account(
                user_id=user["user_id"],
                firstName=user["first_name"],
                lastName=user["last_name"],
                email=user["email"],
                username=user["username"],
                password=user["password"],
                accountKEY=user["AccountKEY"],
            )

            self.users.append(newUser)
        print(self.users)
    else:
        print("""'AccInformation' adlı Dosya bulunamadı.""")
```

Comment: The contents of the json file are as follows; 

 ["{\"user_id\": 518990642826, \"ad\": \"Asdf\", \"soyad\": \"CCCC\", \"email\": \"eee@gmail.com\" , \"kullanıcı adı\": \"Einsatzgruppens\", \"parola\": \"123456\", \"accountKEY\": \"31AI-TR9F-6GMP-S7DE-KJOC-V0Z4\"}"]

I've corrected my codes, and it's the same code you're writing now. I'm getting the following error. My goal is to create new users and save them to the json file.

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: So the issue is with the JSON itself. To put it simply, it is a list with a single string as its contents. The first `"` and the last `" ` are the only non escaped quotation marks. If you put a \ in front of a quotation mark in JSON you escape it. Do a find & replace, replacing `\"` with `" `, and remove the first  and last ones. It then becomes the JSON you need...

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem. That's exactly what the problem was : " user = json.load(user)"

Ben bunu şöyle düzelttim : "user = json.loads(user)".

He's working without problems right now. I hope he doesn't cause me any trouble in the future:)

Thank you all individually for your time.